# google map just display zooming buttons but NOT the map, And have message like 'GC_FOR_ALLOC freed' when display map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to embed Google map into my app.

But the app just display the zooming buttons, I couldn’t see the map.
When I switch to other application and switch back. The map show!

And I want to know what the problem of my app is? How to fix that?

This is what I do:

```
public final static int HANDLER_SHOW_GOOGLEMAP = 4;
public final static int HANDLER_HIDE_GOOGLEMAP = 5;

private final int ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_ADD = 0;
private final int ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_SHOW = 1;
private final int ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_HIDE = 2;

private WeakReference<MyActivity> mActivity;
private LinearLayout m_mapLayout;
private MapFragment m_mapFragment;

public MyHandler(MyActivity activity) {
    super(activity);
    this.mActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(activity);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    switch (msg.what) {
    case HANDLER_SHOW_GOOGLEMAP:
        showGoogleMap();
        break;
    case HANDLER_HIDE_GOOGLEMAP:
        hideGoogleMap();
        break;
    }
}

private void showGoogleMap() {
    initGoogleMap();
    m_mapLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    googleMapFragmentTransaction(ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_SHOW);

    MyActivity theActivity = this.mActivity.get();
    FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout) theActivity.getWindow()
            .getDecorView();
    if (null == viewGroup.findViewById(m_mapLayout.getId())) {
        viewGroup.addView(m_mapLayout);
    }
}

private void hideGoogleMap() {
    initGoogleMap();
    m_mapLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    googleMapFragmentTransaction(ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_HIDE);

    MyActivity theActivity = this.mActivity.get();
    FrameLayout viewGroup = (FrameLayout) theActivity.getWindow()
            .getDecorView();
    if (null != viewGroup.findViewById(m_mapLayout.getId())) {
        viewGroup.removeView(m_mapLayout);
    }
}

private void initGoogleMap() {
    if (null != m_mapLayout) {
        return;
    }

    m_mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();

    MyActivity theActivity = this.mActivity.get();
    m_mapLayout = new LinearLayout(theActivity);

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 480);

    m_mapLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    m_mapLayout.setId(100011);
    m_mapLayout.setY(200);

    googleMapFragmentTransaction(ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_ADD);
}

private void googleMapFragmentTransaction(int enumTransaction) {
    MyActivity theActivity = this.mActivity.get();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = theActivity.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    switch (enumTransaction) {
    case ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_ADD:
        fragmentTransaction.add(m_mapLayout.getId(), m_mapFragment);
        break;
    case ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_SHOW:
        fragmentTransaction.show(m_mapFragment);
        break;
    case ENUM_GOOGLE_FRAGMENT_HIDE:
        fragmentTransaction.hide(m_mapFragment);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

i have not enough reputation to upload pictures, and this is the link of picture:
http://imgdata.hoop8.com/1309/336989570575.png

Comment: The GC part is common and can be filtered by: ^(?!.*(nativeGetEnabledTags)|(GC_)).*$ on message (LogCat filter setting)

Comment: http://imgdata.hoop8.com/1309/836989570575.png

Comment: @cYrixmorten: thanks for you answer, do you know how to fix the problem about the empty map?

Comment: GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.zOrderOnTop(true);
m_mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(options); i finally display map successfully, by using this codes.